# Dynamic allocation of class array with protected destructor

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, language-lawyer

If I have a class defined like

```
class A {
protected:
    ~A(){ }
};
```

then I can dynamically allocate the individual as well as array of objects like

```
A* ptr1 = new A;
A* ptr2 = new A[10];
```

However when I define the constructor for this class

```
class A {
public:
    A(){}
protected:
    ~A(){ }
};
```

then I can create individual objects with

```
A* ptr = new A;
```

but when I try to dynamically allocate the array of object with

```
A* ptr = new A[10];
```

compiler(gcc-5.1 and Visual Studio 2015) starts complaining that A::~A() is inaccessible.

Can anyone explain about:-

1- Why is the difference in behavior with constructor being defined and not defined.

2- When the constructor is defined why I am allowed to create individual object and not array of object.

Comment: Just tested this with clang (Apple LLVM version 8.0.0 clang-800.0.42.1). It behaves differently from gcc and complains at `new A[10]` regardless whether `A` has a explicitly  declared public constructor or whether said constructor is `noexcept`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Rejecting an array-`new` with a protected destructor is correct, as per C++11, §5.3.4 ¶17:

> If the new-expression creates an object or an array of objects of class type, access and ambiguity control are done for the allocation function, the deallocation function (12.5), and the constructor (12.1). **If the new expression creates an array of objects of class type, access and ambiguity control are done for the destructor (12.4).**

(emphasis added; almost exactly the same wording is used in C++03, §5.3.4 ¶16; C++14 moves some stuff around, but that doesn't seem to change the core of the issue - see *@Baum mit Augen*'s answer)

That comes from the fact that `new[]` succeeds only if only all the elements have been constructed, and wants to avoid leaking objects in case one of the costructor calls fails; thus, if it manages to construct - say - the first 9 objects but the 10th fails with an exception, it has to destruct the first 9 before propagating the exception.

Notice that this restriction logically wouldn't be required if the constructor was declared as `noexcept`, but still the standard doesn't seem to have any exception in this regard.

---

So, here gcc is technically wrong in the first case, which, as far as the standard is concerned, should be rejected as well, although I'd argue that "morally" gcc does the right thing (as in practice there's no way that the default constructor of `A` can ever throw).

Comment: thanks for digging our the standardese. This is exactly what I suspected: **defect in the standard**.

Comment: @Walter: The standard just doesn't support all that one would want to do and could technically have done if supported. That's not a defect, it is a possible shortcoming. It's subjective because to others avoiding more complexity in the standard, can be worth more. A similar shortcoming: the standard doesn't support counter-variant arguments. The same argument applies: although some people could want it, to others it would just be added complexity for marginal (if any) gain.

Comment: Regarding the standard wording, having a `noexcept` constructor may not be enough to guarantee that no exception can be thrown during the construction of the array. The constructor may have a parameter with a default argument that is used in the call, and that initialization may throw. I don't think handling simple cases like the example in the question would be worth the added complexity in the wording. Also, the way this is specified here is consistent with how other kinds of subobjects are handled in [class.base.init]. cc @Walter

Comment: @bogdan Okay for the consistenty, but get it how the **default** constructor has a parameter? If a class has a constructor `the_class::the_class() noexcept` and it throws, then `terminate()` must be called.

Comment: @Walter `the_class::the_class(other_class = other_class{}) noexcept` is a default constructor according to [\[class.ctor\]/4](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.ctor#4).

Comment: @bogdan no problem: if the constructor of the default argument throws, `terminate()` is called, when the search for a handler reaches the `noexcept` constructor. No need to destruct anything. `noexcept` does not guarantee anything about whether or not an exception is thrown, it merely allows to call `std::terminate()` if this happened and is not caught before exiting the `noexcept` function.

Comment: @Walter No, in that case the search for a handler does not reach the `noexcept` constructor. Parameter initialization (and destruction) happens in the context of the caller ([\[expr.call\]/4](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.call#4)). Whether the function being called is `noexcept` or not is irrelevant in this case. See also [\[except.spec\]/6.2](http://eel.is/c++draft/except.spec#6.2). That being said, I've just found out that MSVC implements this incorrectly for arrays, so your comment has prompted a bug report (GCC and Clang do it correctly).

Comment: @bogdan Thanks for clarifying. What's the link to the bug reports?

Comment: @Walter https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/3119375/vc-15-rc-exception-from-default-argument-during-array-initialization-is-handled-incorrectly

Answer (score 10):

As it turns out, gcc is not correct here. In N4141 (C++14), we have:

> If the
>   new-expression creates an array of objects of class type, the destructor is potentially invoked (12.4).

(5.3.4/19 [expr.new]) and

> A
>   program is ill-formed if a destructor that is potentially invoked is deleted or not accessible from the context
>   of the invocation.

(12.4/11 [class.dtor]). **So both array cases should be rejected.** (Clang does get that right, [live](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/kHR1ru1EV8m495Jb).)

The reason for that is, as mentioned by others and by my old, incorrect answer, that the construction of elements of class type can potentially fail with an exception. When that happens, the destructor of all fully constructed elements must be invoked, and thus the destructor must be accessible.

That limitation does not apply when allocating a single element with `operator new` (without the `[]`), because there can be no fully constructed instance of the class if the single constructor call fails.

Comment: Why is the destructor potentially invoked in `new A[10];` when `A::A() noexcept;`?

Comment: @Walter Standard says so. vOv If you can come up with a good usecase for the logically valid exception based on `noexcept` you can write a proposal to change that.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not a language lawyer (very familiar with the standard), but suspect the answer is along the lines of that given earlier by Baum mit Augen (deleted, so only those with sufficient reputation can see it).

If the construction of subsequent array elements fails and throws an exception, then the already constructed elements will need to be deleted, requiring access to the destructor.

However, if the constructor is `noexcept`, this can be ruled out and access to the destructor is not required. The fact that gcc and clang both still complain even in this case, may well be a **compiler bug**. That is, the compiler fails to take into account that the constructor is `noexcept`. Alternatively, the compilers may be within the standard, in which case, this smells like a **defect in the standard**.